# MySQL Trigger IF Condition

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to fill some column values in a table upon insertion on another table and have a condition for particular column. I use the trigger :

```
CREATE TRIGGER inserttrigger AFTER INSERT ON table1 FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO table2 SET col1 = NEW.col1, col2 = NEW.col2;  IF LENGTH(NEW.col3) > 20 THEN SET col3 = NEW.col3 END IF;
```

I get the syntax error near IF condition as :

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER inserttrigger AFTER INSERT ON table1 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO table2 
   SET col1 = NEW.col1, 
       col2 = NEW.col2,
       col3 = case when LENGTH(NEW.col3) > 20 
                   then NEW.col3
              end;
END
|
delimiter ;
```

Comment: I get the following : "**ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'col3'**", where col3 is of varchar type and col1, clo2 of INT type

Comment: See my update. `col3` needs to be in the `insert` statement.